# Hadoop java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-crunch

I am using Apache Crunch to write some map-reduce code. I have the following class which holds some data that is passed around in the map-reduce code, but I get an exception - not sure why.

Here is the class interface

```
package com.ca.analytics.pa.datamodel;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public interface MilestoneDatum extends Comparable<MilestoneDatum>, Serializable {
    public String                        getMilestoneID();
    public String                        getMilestoneDefinitionID();
    public String                        getCreateDtTm(); 
    public String                        getClient(); 
    public String                        getDomain(); 
    public String                        getUserName(); 
    public String                        getPrimaryEventID(); 
    public String                        getSourceID(); 
    public String                        getInsertDtTm(); 
    public List<MilestoneAttributeDatum> getAttributes();
    public void                          setAttributes(List<MilestoneAttributeDatum> attributes); 

    public static class BuilderFactory {
        public static DatumBuilder<MilestoneDatum> create() {
            return new MilestoneDatumImpl.Builder();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the class implementation itself.. (I have a default empty constructor here..)

```
    package com.ca.analytics.pa.datamodel;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.common.base.MoreObjects;
import com.google.common.base.Objects;
import com.google.common.collect.ComparisonChain;
import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;

public class MilestoneDatumImpl implements MilestoneDatum {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5034829549271201929L;

    public MilestoneDatumImpl() {} // Kept public for Serialization support

    // Milestone
    private String                        milestoneID;
    private String                        milestoneDefinitionID;
    private String                        createDtTm;
    private String                        client;
    private String                        domain;
    private String                        userName;
    private String                        primaryEventID;
    private String                        sourceID;
    private String                        insertDtTm;
    private List<MilestoneAttributeDatum> attributes;

    public String getMilestoneID() {
        return milestoneID;
    }

    public String getMilestoneDefinitionID() {
        return milestoneDefinitionID;
    }

    public String getCreateDtTm() {
        return createDtTm;
    }

    public String getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getPrimaryEventID() {
        return primaryEventID;
    }

    public String getSourceID() {
        return sourceID;
    }

    public String getInsertDtTm() {
        return insertDtTm;
    }

    public List<MilestoneAttributeDatum> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(List<MilestoneAttributeDatum> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    public static class Builder implements DatumBuilder<MilestoneDatum> {
        // Milestone
        private String                        milestoneID;
        private String                        milestoneDefinitionID;
        private String                        createDtTm;
        private String                        client;
        private String                        domain;
        private String                        userName;
        private String                        primaryEventID;
        private String                        sourceID;
        private String                        insertDtTm;
        private List<MilestoneAttributeDatum> attributes;

        public Builder withMilestoneID(String milestoneID) {
            this.milestoneID = milestoneID;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withMilestoneDefinitionID(String milestoneDefinitionID) {
            this.milestoneDefinitionID = milestoneDefinitionID;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withCreateDtTm(String createDtTm) {
            this.createDtTm = createDtTm;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withClient(String client) {
            this.client = client;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withDomain(String domain) {
            this.domain = domain;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withPrimaryEventID(String primaryEventID) {
            this.primaryEventID = primaryEventID;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withSourceID(String sourceID) {
            this.sourceID = sourceID;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withInsertDtTm(String insertDtTm) {
            this.insertDtTm = insertDtTm;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withAttributes(List<MilestoneAttributeDatum> attributes) {
            this.attributes = attributes;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public MilestoneDatum build() {
            MilestoneDatumImpl datum = new MilestoneDatumImpl();  
            datum.milestoneID              = this.milestoneID;
            datum.milestoneDefinitionID    = this.milestoneDefinitionID;
            datum.createDtTm               = this.createDtTm;
            datum.client                   = this.client;
            datum.domain                   = this.domain;
            datum.userName                 = this.userName;
            datum.primaryEventID           = this.primaryEventID;
            datum.sourceID                 = this.sourceID;
            datum.insertDtTm               = this.insertDtTm;
            datum.attributes               = this.attributes;

            return datum;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MilestoneDatum that) {
        return ComparisonChain.start()
            .compare(this.milestoneID          , that.getMilestoneID())              
            .compare(this.milestoneDefinitionID, that.getMilestoneDefinitionID())    
            .compare(this.createDtTm           , that.getCreateDtTm())              
            .compare(this.client               , that.getClient())
            .compare(this.domain               , that.getDomain())
            .compare(this.userName             , that.getUserName())                
            .compare(this.primaryEventID       , that.getPrimaryEventID())          
            .compare(this.sourceID             , that.getSourceID())                
            .compare(this.insertDtTm           , that.getInsertDtTm())    
            .compare(this.attributes,            that.getAttributes(), Ordering.<MilestoneAttributeDatum>natural().lexicographical())
            .result();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(
            this.milestoneID,
            this.milestoneDefinitionID,
            this.createDtTm,
            this.client,
            this.domain,
            this.userName,
            this.primaryEventID,
            this.sourceID,
            this.insertDtTm,
            this.attributes
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)                  return true;
        if (obj  == null)                 return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

        MilestoneDatum other = (MilestoneDatum) obj;

        return Objects.equal(this.milestoneID          , other.getMilestoneID())
            && Objects.equal(this.milestoneDefinitionID, other.getMilestoneDefinitionID())
            && Objects.equal(this.createDtTm           , other.getCreateDtTm())
            && Objects.equal(this.client               , other.getClient())
            && Objects.equal(this.domain               , other.getDomain())
            && Objects.equal(this.userName             , other.getUserName())
            && Objects.equal(this.primaryEventID       , other.getPrimaryEventID())
            && Objects.equal(this.sourceID             , other.getSourceID())
            && Objects.equal(this.insertDtTm           , other.getInsertDtTm())
            && Objects.equal(this.attributes           , other.getAttributes());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
            .add("milestoneID"          , milestoneID)
            .add("milestoneDefinitionID", milestoneDefinitionID)
            .add("createDtTm"           , createDtTm)
            .add("client"               , client)
            .add("domain"               , domain)
            .add("userName"             , userName)
            .add("primaryEventID"       , primaryEventID)
            .add("sourceID"             , sourceID)
            .add("insertDtTm"           , insertDtTm)
            .add("attributes"           , attributes)
            .toString();
    }
}
```

Here's the exception I get during the map-phase..

```
2019-01-10 12:44:30,537 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.cerner.ca.analytics.pa.datamodel.MilestoneDatum.<init>()
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.newInstance(SpecificData.java:338)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.newRecord(SpecificData.java:354)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData.newRecord(ReflectData.java:782)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:220)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:144)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.next(DataFileStream.java:233)
    at org.apache.crunch.types.avro.AvroRecordReader.nextKeyValue(AvroRecordReader.java:77)
    at org.apache.crunch.impl.mr.run.CrunchRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CrunchRecordReader.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.cerner.ca.analytics.pa.datamodel.MilestoneDatum.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.newInstance(SpecificData.java:332)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the compiler cannot find the () method within MilestoneDatum. Try to update the version of MilestoneDatum that your code is consuming.

Comment: My apologies, but not sure I understand what we mean  by 'updating the class version'... I recompiled the code and retested (also changed serialversionUID if that matters..)

Comment: My bad, I assumed you were working within a repository (github, etc.) if you have one, your pom.xml file would show the version of the project that the class is contained within. Usually to fix this issue, I just change the version number to that of the latest release.